# Альтернативы позиционирования

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

Мой первый вопрос на стеке)

В чём суть: https://prnt.sc/19b0mrv

Как сверстать содержимое данной секции, без использования флоат, позишн, флекс и грид? Есть какие то альтернативы исполнения?

Comment: Тут только таблицей можно это сделать, но это недружелюбное решение будет к пользователю вашего сервиса. Лучше всего сделать через Flex или Grid. Но интересно, почему не хочешь на этих методах верстки?

Comment: Интересно было узнать про альтернативы. А так конечно первое что на ум приходит это флоат, но его вроде как не рекомендуется использовать. Следом Флекс... и тут пришла мысль, а какие ещё интересные альтернативы могут быть при данном макете)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`без использования флоат, позишн, флекс и грид`

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
  vertical-align: top;
}
video{
  display:block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%">
        <h1>Заголовок H1</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td width="50%">
        <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls></video>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```